# Java List size() performance and tips

Tags: java, performance, list

I want to know the performance of `.size()` method. Does this method returns a reference from the number of objects in the list (like a class member which is incremented every time when an object is added to the list)? Or does it iterate through all objects?

Which one is more efficient?

Calling `.size()` every time:

```
List<Vector3> objects = getCoords();

for (int x = 0; x < objects.size(); x++){
   for (int y = 0; y < objects.size(); y++){
      for (int z = 0; z < objects.size(); z++){
         drawShape(x, y, z);
      }
   }
}
```

Or by saving to a local variable:

```
List<Vector3> objects = getCoords();
int size = objects.size();

for (int x = 0; x < size; x++){
   for (int y = 0; y < size; y++){
      for (int z = 0; z < size; z++){
         drawShape(x, y, z);
      }
   }
}
```

Let's assume that we have **> 30.000** objects in the list.

Which one is more faster/efficient?

Does it matter if we use an `ArrayList<T>` or a `List<T>` ?

What about simple statements: `.size()` or `.isEmpty()`

```
if (objects != null && objects.size() > 0){
   doThis();
}
```

or by calling `.isEmpty()`

```
if (objects != null && !objects.isEmpty()){
   doSomethingElse();
}
```

Comment: Class member, if memory serves. You can dig through the source code of the various implementations to find out, but I really doubt the iteration approach would be taken. Far too much of a performance penalty to warrant the 4 byte memory savings. Your two loops *can* be equivalent if the sizes don't change, and I *think* that the JITC in that case can turn one into the other. Whether you use `ArrayList<T>` or `List<T>` is a matter of flexibility. In the end, you choose the actual implementation. `size()` and `isEmpty()` solve different problems.

Comment: What type of `List` does `getCoords()` return? It probably doesn't matter, but it's worth noting that `List` is merely an interface, so implementations of it may behave differently.

Comment: No need to "dig". Check out the source code. As for the ArrayList vs List: One is an interface. Keeping an interface on the left of the assignment has its advantages (more on that somewhere here on SO)

Answer (score 3):

Java `List` uses a instance variable to handle the size. It is incremented when you add, and decremented when you decrease. Calling `list.size()` returns a variable, and is therefore O(1).

`List.size()` would (theoretically) look something like:

```
public int size() {
    return this.size;
}
```

Calling `List.isEmpty()` is a boolean check on whether the instance variable `size` is equal to 0 or not.

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (this.size==0);
}
```

Since this is a instance variable, it doesn't matter (from what I know) what type of `List` you use, since all inherit a general interface and have the required `add()` and other functions.

Comment: This depends on the implementation of `List` interface.

Comment: I think all standard `List`s store the size, but it's conceivable a user-made one would not.

Comment: It'd be less ambiguous to say _instance_ variable instead of _class_ variable. The second one often refers to static member variables.

Comment: @keyser good catch, my answer has been edited.

Comment: Java `List` doesn't use any instance variables, since it's an interface, not a class.

Comment: Yes, one could throw in the word "implementation" somewhere :p